# Скопировать из файла F1 в файл F2 все строки, в которых есть слова, совпадающие с первым словом.

Tags: файлы, c

Использовать файловый ввод/вывод С <stdio.h>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define  BUFSIZE   512
#define  BUFWORD   64

static int first_word(const char** s, char* w);
static int is_word(const char* s, const char* w);

int main(void) {
    char  line[BUFSIZE];
    char  word[BUFWORD];
    const char* ptr;

    FILE* fin = fopen("in.txt", "rt");
    if(fin == NULL)
        return 1;

    FILE* fout = fopen("out.txt", "wt+");

    while((ptr = fgets(line, sizeof(line), fin)) != NULL) {
        if(! first_word(&ptr, word))
            continue;
        if(is_word(ptr, word))
            fputs(line, fout);
    }
    fclose(fin);

    fflush(fout);
    fclose(fout);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

//выделяем(копируем) первое слово в строке
static int first_word(const char** s, char* w){
    const char* p = *s;
    char* t = w;
    while(*p && ! isalpha(*p))
        ++p;
    while(isalpha(*p) && (w - t < BUFWORD))
        *w++ = *p++;
    *w = '\0';
    *s = p;
    return (w != t);
}

// проверяем слова в строке(не подстроки)
static int is_word(const char* s, const char* w) {
    const char*  t = s;
    const size_t n = strlen(w);
    while((s = strstr(s, w)) != NULL) {
        if(((t == s) || ! isalpha(*(s - 1)) && ! isalpha(*(s + n))))
            return 1;
        s += n;
    }
    return 0;
}
```